# SERVERLESS: Error: RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a serverless project. But it gives an error when giving the `serverless` command on the cmd. Please help me to solve this.

first I installed the serverless with '`npm install -g serverless`' command. Then I gave '`serverless`' command. So following error was displayed on the cmd.

---

```
C:\Geethma\myFiles\serverlessTutorial>serverless

Creating a new serverless project

? What do you want to make? AWS - Node.js - Starter
? What do you want to call this project? aws-node-project
Environment: win32, node 16.15.0, framework 3.18.2, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\geethma.rathnayake\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:962:111)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\Users\geethma.rathnayake\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a machine provided by an employer, they may have installed self-signed SSL certificates in order to connect to internal systems or run fleet management software.

You can override strict checking in Node by either prepending the command with `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 serverless`, or permanently with `npm config set strict-ssl false`.

Answer (score 1):

I had checked with Aaron's answer, but it didn't work for my case.

Issue on my side was with my company's VPN, as it was blocking sending/receiving the data. I went with the below steps that solved my issue.

**Solution**

1. Try disabling the VPN.
2. Run the command again.
3. Verify if it works.

Also make sure that your IAM user has necessary privileges to perform this by attaching necessary `policy` in the AWS's IAM User page.